# How to store current URL in cookie, and use that cookie to check in other page, if available then redirect to the same URL in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, ecmascript-6, frontend

Let me explain my scenario. I have a query string in my current page URl, if that exists then i need to store the URL in a cookie. Once i click sign in, i will be redirected to another page, then i will check if this cookie exist there or not, if it exist then it will redirect me back to the current page.

```
if(queryString = 'data'){
  document.cookie = window.location.href;
  let abc = document.cookie;
}
```

i am not able to save URL to cookie and use, can anyone help me in this?

Comment: To create a cookie by assigning a value to `document.cookie`, that value must start with `name=value` at least. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#write_a_new_cookie

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because multiple values are/need to be saved in the cookie. So my advise would be to store it attached to an parameter like `url={url}` and create a function that can get the correct value like shown in the snippet below.

```js
let url = window.location.href;
console.log("Default url:", url);
document.cookie = `url=${url}`;

let wrong = document.cookie;
console.log("Full cookie:", wrong);

function getCookie (name) {
    let value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
    let parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
    if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}

let right = getCookie("url");
console.log("Only url:", right);
```

The snippet won't work due to Stackoverflow rejecting the use of cookies in snippets.

Comment: so i can i get this getCookie in any page?? and use @Tim567